# Origin of Cone in NAT naming convention

Tags: nat

I am reading about `Full Cone`, `Restricted Cone` and `Port Restricted Cone NATs`. While how they work is clear, I am having trouble coming up with a justification for such naming. The `"Cone"` probably has nothing to with geometrical shape. Does cone refer to something else or is this one of the historical leftovers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are just confusing names for the behavior of the NAT.  Think of a cone more as a funnel, like you're making things combine into a smaller space as it funnels down.

Full cone: 1-to-1 (full NAT)

Restricted cone: Many-to-one (like a NAT for a subnet to all use the same public IP address)

Port Restricted cone: The same as above, but also restricting to a specific port